# How to make org-export give more messages when it fails

Tags: org-export

When I tried to `org-export` to html file, this message showed up in **Messages** or `minibuffer`:

```
htmlize-color-to-rgb: Wrong type argument: stringp, 3
```

nothing more.

Actually another message showed up before this one:

```
org-html-table-cell: Args out of range: [left right right], 3
```

I remember an abnormal place about my table in this file, so I can just search string for the position.

But this org file contains more than 1000 lines and I don't have clue where and what(even though it mentioned `rgb`) is going wrong so it is really hard to check page by page manually.

`org-export`-to-html function works successfully for my another org file, failed for this one, but I think it should give more than just one sentence without even mentioning which line causes an error.

So is there any variable to turn on for more verbose messages if `org-export` fails?

Comment: I think Org writes a log of an export into a separate buffer, for PDF this is typically named `*Org PDF LaTeX Output*` it should be something similar for HTML I'd imagine (sorry, can't try it right now).

Comment: @wvxvw It should do that, but it produced no other buffer related to org, all its message is the message I provided.

Comment: M-x toggle-debug-on-error

Comment: Related: [How to debug org export to beamer?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7157/504)

Comment: I've looked now into `ox.el` and `ox-html.el` and it indeed doesn't look like Org logs anything related to HTML export. So, I guess that the way is as kuanyui suggested: start debugging and see where it breaks.